# replacing value of a variable for missing values of a variable in R

Tags: r, replace, dplyr

I have generated a variable using dplyr now my interest is to replace values conditioned on missing values in another variable. Please suggest. Here is my command:

```
long_nsdp <- long_nsdp %>% mutate(lnsdp=log(nsdp))
long_nsdp <- long_nsdp %>% 
             mutate(lnsdp=ifelse(nsdp=="",
             log(nsdp+2),lnsdp))
```

Where, I am using `nsdp==""` for missing values in variable `nsdp`.

Comment: Please show a few lines of example data and expected output.

Comment: I am `assuming` (as you mentioned the blanks as `""`) the `nsdp` column will be either `character` or `factor` class.  So taking `log` on those is not getting the result you expected.  Convert the column to `numeric` with `as.numeric` so that `''` will be automatically convert to `NA` and then use the `is.na` in the solution.

Comment: I don't understand the code line `mutate(lnsdp=ifelse(nsdp=="", log(nsdp+2),lnsdp)` - If `nsdp==""`, you want `log(nsdp+2)`? But, `nsdp` is blank in this case, so you could directly write `mutate(lnsdp=ifelse(nsdp=="", 0.6931472, lnsdp)`.

Answer (score 1):

change you `nsdp=""` to `is.na(nsdp)`

or better still - use `base R` to

```
long_nsdp$lnsdp[is.na(long_nsdp$nsdp) | long_nsdp$nsdp="",] <-log(nsdp+2)
```

assuming the original value of this column is nsdp and only for the missing values as stated, an update should occur

Comment: Dear Mor, I thanked all for the help. Given that my interest was in using dplyr so took the is.na idea.